# Windows 10 logon very slow

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-profiles, autologon

I have quite quite common but in details very specific problem. Windows 10 machine logon takes minutes. 3-5, maybe even more.

1. I tried to edit and turn off all startup programs
2. I tried to run with only system services
3. I tried without any services
4. Safe mode
   ... stil the same..

But logons almost immediately with new test user. Both just local offline accounts.

It's HP 455 G2 - AMD-A8, 8GB DDR3 - but that should not be important.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You seemed  to have narrowed this down to the User Profile (not fixable).  Try backing up your documents and email (and anything else) and then make a new User Profile

Comment: Thank you, but I know. Just wanted to find the reason. Quite self-destructing demand I know :-)

Comment: Any number of things can damage a profile so it is difficult to say what.

Comment: "*I tried to edit and turn off all startup programs*". Did that with Windows Startup only or with something like Sysinternals Autoruns? Maybe it's some other type of Autostart (like scheduled tasks) that aren't part of Windows Startup settings.

Comment: I'll try to dig into that. Almost forgot about this tool, so thank you!

Comment: Check your disks

Comment: So I've spent some time with Autoruns, checking disks and other suggestions. Nothing helped. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

So as John suggested, making new profile was best solution. I knew but wanted to find the reason. So I did new profile and after transfering everything and ending me having two same profiles the first one corrupted started to act normally and logons in few seconds :)
So last time I was looking for a reason when I know the solution :))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).